# stub generation failed with java.net.unknownhostexception

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry, stub

Iam trying to generate stub files using java sunwireless tool kit.
Iam able to open the link in chrome

[image]
Iam getting this error how to resolve it

Comment: Looks like in the wsdl there's an URL the generator can't resolve. Open the WSDL, search for the string in the exception, and make sure the URLs can be resolved by testing them in a browser. Or, check your firewall is not blocking the stub generator.

Comment: how about using eclipse and axis plugin to generate web services , you can google for generating proxy stub using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Save the WSDL as *.xml from your browser, then generate stub, URL is local file's path *.xml;

Notice
WSDL have two status in your browser, normally like this：
http://webservice.webxml.com.cn/WebServices/WeatherWS.asmx
Browser will deal it for you to read
http://webservice.webxml.com.cn/WebServices/WeatherWS.asmx?wsdl
Pure XML